# Creating an aws_api_gateway_account resource returns AccessDeniedException

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

In my terraform script I have the following resource -

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "demo" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = var.apigw_cloudwatch_role_arn
}
```

In the Apply stage, I see the following error -

```
2020/09/21 20:20:48 [ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: Updating API Gateway Account failed: AccessDeniedException: 
    status code: 403, request id: abb0662e-ead2-4d95-b987-7d889088a5ef
```

Is there a specific permission that needs to be attached to the role in order to get rid of this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't tested, but I believe the role needs what's shown below. See more context at the source: "To enable CloudWatch Logs" section at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html

> For common application scenarios, the IAM role could attach the
> managed policy of AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs, which contains
> the following access policy statement:
>
> {
> "Version": "2012-10-17",
> "Statement": [
> {
> "Effect": "Allow",
> "Action": [
> "logs:CreateLogGroup",
> "logs:CreateLogStream",
> "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
> "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
> "logs:PutLogEvents",
> "logs:GetLogEvents",
> "logs:FilterLogEvents"
> ],
> "Resource": "*"
> }
> ] }
>
> The IAM role must also contain the following trust relationship
> statement:
>
> {   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
> {
> "Sid": "",
> "Effect": "Allow",
> "Principal": {
> "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
> },
> "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
> }   ] }

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same problem as @bdev03, took me 2 days to identify the missing permission is "iam:PassRole", be so good if terraform is able to point that out, hope this helps.

Comment: Where are you defining iam:PassRole?

Comment: @dataviews the IAM role or IAM user that is being used by terraform would need this permission.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither this thread (so far) nor the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html) is doing a very good job at solving this problem... The minimal policies required for this action are:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowPassingTheRoleToApiGateway",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "iam:PassRole",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "iam:PassedToService": ["apigateway.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowAPIGatewayUpdate",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
      "apigateway:UpdateRestApiPolicy",
      "apigateway:PATCH",
      "apigateway:GET"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Comment: This post isn't so much more helpful either ;) Which resource needs the policies mentioned by you?